# Iterate over JSON and stored pointers in Swift

Tags: json, swift, loops, dictionary, pointers

After receiving a `JSON` payload from a web request, I need to parse out the data into variables in an `NSObject` subclass.

My variables are declared in the object:

```
var name:String?
var email:String?
var aboutMe:String?
```

Then I start parsing through all the possible data the `JSON` may return:

```
if let name = json["Name"] as? String
{
    self.name = name
}
if let email = json["Email"] as? String
{
    self.email = email
}
if let aboutMe = json["AboutMe"] as? String
{
    self.aboutMe = aboutMe
}
```

This is becoming rather long as we have a lot of data.

I was wanting to shorted it by using a `Dictionary` containing the `JSON` key and the `variable` like this:

```
let varMap:[String:Any?] = [
   "Name": self.name,
   "Email": self.email,
   "AboutMe": self.aboutMe
]
```

Then iterating over them like this:

```
for (key, var variable) in varMap
{
   if let string = json[key]
   {
      variable = string
   }
}
```

The problem here is that the `Dictionary` copies the value from the variable and not a pointer to it, so setting it to a new value has no effect on the variables of the overall object.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying? If not, what other pattern would be a better way to do this instead of having tons of `if` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *JSON* parsing, you can simply use **`Codable`** types.

Let's assume your *JSON* looks like,

```
{
  "name": "Alex",
  "email": "alex@gmail.com",
  "about_Me": "My name is Alex"
}
```

**Models:**

```
class Root: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    let email: String?
    let aboutMe: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, email
        case aboutMe = "about_Me"
    }
}
```

**Parse** the *JSON* `data` like so,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(response) //use response here...
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Does this only work if the json key names are the same as the variable names?

Comment: If they aren't, you can use `CodingKeys` in the `Codable` type and specify your custom key names. I've updated the answer to give an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use updateValue function for that, it finds the property and changes it.

```
if let oldValue = varMap.updateValue(self.name, forKey: "Name") {
    print("The old value of \(oldValue) was replaced with a new one.")
}
```

So you for iteration is;

```
for (key, var variable) in varMap
{
   varMap.updateValue(string, forKey: key )

   //if let string = json[key]
   //{
   //   variable = string
   //}
}
```

After you update the dictionary you can call that part;

```
if let name = json["Name"] as? String
{
    self.name = name
}
if let email = json["Email"] as? String
{
    self.email = email
}
if let aboutMe = json["AboutMe"] as? String
{
    self.aboutMe = aboutMe
}
```

I believe that part in a function, if its not, you can refactor it.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127179-updatevalue

Comment: That is updating the value in the Dictionary. I want to update the value in the variable `self.name`

Comment: How about calling the same code again? I updated the answer.

Comment: I could just use the if statements on their own, but I was looking for a tidier way of doing it by mapping the variable name with the json name.

Comment: So you can check RxSwift, Codable, and ObjectMapper for that but I m confused, you asked for updating the dictionary, and now you are asking to tidy up the if statements.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question isn't clear. I show what I currently do by using `if` statements to check for every `json` key and assign it to it's variable. The `json` keys are not the same as the variable names. I say it's becoming rather long and I tried to shorten the function by assigning the `json` keys and variable names in a Dictionary and iterating over it.

Comment: I just looked up ObjectMapper and it seems I can do away with the `if let`'s and just use single lines like `self.email = json["email"] as? String`. This already makes it much tidier.

Comment: Ok, that is great! You can also look for Codable from JSON parsing. You can save the codable class to disk and it is a more modern way, you even don't have to define the keywords, it can guess automatically :)